# PgSqlExcetion: date/time field value out of range: "4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM"

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, datetime

I want Insert Data Table in DataBase

```
    public void InsertNote(DataTable dataTable)
            {
                var query = new StringBuilder();

                query.Append("INSERT INTO sde.\"Table1\" 
(id, disciplol, date, second_id, note, key) VALUES ");

                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    query.AppendFormat(" ({0}, '{1}', '{2}', {3}, '{4}', '{5}'),", 
row["classid"], row["disciplina"], row["datelesson"], row["student_id"], "", row["key"]);
                }

                // TODO : Review
                query.Replace(',', ';', query.Length - 2, 2);

                var cmd = new PgSqlCommand(query.ToString());

                var con = DB.Sqlconnection;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    // result = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //result = false;
                    log.Error("InsertInTable1", ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
```

In generated CMD I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO sde."RegistruNote" (first_id, discipline, date, second_id, note, key) VALUES  
(131415, 'Painting', '4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM', 432431, 'asd', 'aWbhxZn3X'), 
(131415, 'Painting', '4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM', 432432, 'fas', '3Dl8YCSgX'), 
(131415, 'Painting', '4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM', 432433, 'asd', '8RiBgcjuL'), 
(131415, 'Painting', '4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM', 432434, 'fds', '8rAW1VfC7'), 
(131415, 'Painting', '4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM', 432435, 'gfd', 'LhRP2y5Ji'), 
(131415, 'Painting', '4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM', 432436, 'wer', 'lGVa5boYs'), 
(131415, 'Painting', '4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM', 432437, 'wer', 'hbFfo2zNg'), 
(131415, 'Painting', '4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM', 432438, 'we', 'xEq7iAhMi'), 
(131415, 'Painting', '4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM', 432439, 'rew', 'drFNV9sCm'), 
(131415, 'Painting', '4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM', 432410, 'tw', 'dJ5XwJLQy');
```

In catch I have this exception:
PgSqlExcetion
date/time field value out of range: "4/20/2012 12:00:00 AM"

Where do I have to convert the date to dd.mm.yyyy format ?

Comment: foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
       {
        query.AppendFormat(" ({0}, '{1}', '{2}', {3}, '{4}', '{5}'),", 
        
        row["classid"], row["disciplina"], 
    
        /*here I have indicated the format*/
        (row["datelesson"] is DateTime ? (DateTime) row["datelesson"] : 
    
               new DateTime()).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), row["student_id"], "", row["key"]);
                    
    }

 Now the format is dd.mm.yyyy and inserts are working )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at using [PgSqlParameter](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/Devart.Data.PostgreSql~Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand~Parameters.html) objects rather than building up your whole query as a string - it may be the case that the server is not set up to recognise the locale that your client is using.